# Run mac os x app method from command line

Tags: php, objective-c, macos, shell, command-line

It may sound weird, but I want to execute mac application method from command line.
I have an application, which does some task. I need to execute that task while app is running when my PHP receives an event.
I am able to execute that application using `php shell_exec()` function, but when the app is already open I cannot run specific method using `shell`. **Is it possible or not?**

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

If it is not so clear, I want to do something like this.
`open MyCreated.app -callMethod "myMethod"`

Comment: You need to provide more details, for example the command you are looking to run. Have you tried running this command in the terminal when the app is open? have you tried just `exec()`?

Comment: If I knew the command probably I could try to execute it. I am able to run a shell command from php, but what I want is something like this `Garnik$ execute MyOwn.app viewDidLoad` for example, or any other method.

Comment: You can create another project with the same functionality of this method and run it or think of something connected with Apple Script to perform the same function as the method .

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to do this magic with Apple Script, but I'm very fresh to it :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want

- make `MyCreated.app` scriptable - e.g. it will respond to events what you defines.
- after, you can use AppleScript (and from Yosemite - JavaScript too) for sending events to your app - and it will respond.

some docs:

- [Scriptable apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2002/tn2106.html)
- about the new [JavaScript OSA](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/)

Finally, now you can write full-blown applications e.g. `MyCreated.app` in pure JavaScript (Without touching Xcode). One very nice, step-by-step tutorial is [here](http://tylergaw.com/articles/building-osx-apps-with-js).